# What does "leaving somebody flat" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

From the lyrics of [*Ma Baker*](http://www.metrolyrics.com/ma-baker-lyrics-boney-m.html):

> Freeze I'm ma Baker
>   Put your hands in the air and give me all your money
>   This is the story of ma Baker the meanest cat from old Chicago town
>   She was the meanest cat
>   In old Chicago town
>   She was the meanest cat
>   She really mowed them down
>   She had no heart at all
>   No no no heart at all
>   She was the meanest cat
>   For she was really tough
>   **She left her husband flat**
>   He wasn't tough enough
>   She took her boys along
>   Cause they were mean and strong

When saying she left her husband flat, does this mean that she left her husband's apartment or does it mean she actually flattened her husband like the people she mowed down at the bank?

Comment: "flat" in idioms of The Free Dictionary. Three uses.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+flat

Comment: If you think about it, you've already ruled out the meaning of _flat_ = _apartment_, because then it would say, _She left her **husband's** flat_.

Answer (score 4):

*"Leave flat"* is an expression which means either

> To take a person's complete assets and walk away, leaving him with nothing.

or

> ditching somebody all of a sudden and walking away.

Since ma Baker is a ruthless woman who steals money, she could do both to her husband. So either meanings are valid. I personally feel it is the latter.

Check out the usage of this term [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+flat).

Answer (score 1):

> She left her husband flat

The phrase here is **flat on his back** (i.e. *Knocked Out*).

Imagine a tree falling. The inference is that *she* punched him so hard he fell flat on his back (unconscious) and while he was *out cold* she packed her things, took the kids and left.

Comment: It's possible it means this, but I think the normal idiomatic meanings (linked to by @VarunKN) make sense. Ultimately we can't say for sure. The writer was probably just looking for a phrase that rhymed with *cat*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When we were children ...a friend would leave us "FLAT" or even "FLAT LEAVE"...if they chose to leave (without notice) our play date activity to run off and play with a "cooler" friend. BUT of course I have heard the term "FLAT BROKE" so that makes sense in this context too as I read it.